# Force latexdiff not to parse tikzpicture environments

Tags: tikz-pgf, latexdiff

Is it possible to force `latexdiff` not to parse TikZ figures? When I run `latexdiff` on a document where there is something like

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
...
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}  % corrected typo
```

It parses also the TikZ figure code and the diff is not a correct TikZ figure anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it is hard to generate a correct diff for TikZ figures I think your approach to exclude them completely is the best way.

You can call `latexdiff` with the parameter `-c <config file>`. In the configuration file you can specify which enviroments `latexdiff` should ignore. Taken from the manual:

> PICTUREENV
>   Within environments whose name matches the regular expression in PICTUREENV
>   all latexdiﬀ markup is removed (in pathologic cases this might lead to inconsistent markup but this situation should be rare).
>   Default: (?:picture|DIFnomarkup)[\w\d*@]*

So with the regex `(?:picture|tikzpicture|DIFnomarkup)[\w\d*@]*` it should not parse TikZ figures.

Comment: That is, you should type `latexdiff -c "PICTUREENV=(?:picture|tikzpicture|DIFnomarkup)[\w\d*@]*" old.tex new.tex > diff.tex`.
`