# Latexdiff "fixes" and config files

Tags: best-practices, tools, latexdiff

[Latexdiff](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff), while overall very useful, sometimes requires manual fixes to its configuration variables and default options; for instance, [excluding the `tikzpicture` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78011/force-latexdiff-not-to-parse-tikzpicture-environments) from the diff algorithm seems necessary, or the default `ARRENV` includes `[pbvBV]matrix` but not `smallmatrix`.

Is there a maintained set of configuration files, or at least something better than starting from scratch to build my own list of exceptions?

Comment: Writing as the author of latexdiff, I am not aware that there is such a central repository although there would be clearly a merit in this. If people send specific fixes to me, more often than not they can be incorporated into the latexdiff core (many minor improvements over the years were realised this way). Otherwise, where special configuration options would interfere with the standard operation I could place the set of options required within a special 'contrib' folder in the latexdiff distribution on CTAN.

Comment: @frederik Thanks, sounds great. I did not know that it was still actively developed, probably I should have asked you before. Do you have a bug tracker or should I contact you directly via e-mail? For now I am just using `ARRENV = (?:array|[pbvBV]matrix|smallmatrix|cases)` as a custom modification. On top of that, I have thrown some commands that my co-authors love to use without parentheses such as `\mathbb` and `\tilde` into SAFECMD, but I am not sure whether it is a good approach in general.

Comment: Well, it is active development at a really slow pace. I have included the smallmatrix modification (and tikzpicture) in the next version (1.04+; not yet released).   There is a bug tracker at the berlios webpage (link in man page of latexdiff) but as this repository is due to go offline soon, and I haven't migrated yet to a different repo, you can also send me an email (address also in manpage)

Comment: @frederik Ok, I'll send you other patches in future if I find other improvements to the regexps. Thanks for creating this great tool!